# Do I need to change the configuration of the admin key after installing APISIX?

Tags: apache-apisix

After I successfully installed APISIX, I found that the configuration file contains admin key information and all control requests need to contain this credential, do I need to change this configuration? How do I make the change take effect?

Answer (score 0):

for security reasons, we would encourage any users to generate a different API key before using Apache APISIX, please check its documentation[1].

NOTE: API Key is only a string, you can generate a new one in your preferred way. For me, I would use https://www.random.org/strings/.

[1] https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/admin-api/
[2] https://github.com/apache/apisix/blob/master/conf/config.yaml#L46